# Getting value of datalist input, using v-model clears the datalist

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a datalist filled with options, and an input linked to that data list. When the user makes a selection i'm using v-model to send that value to the Vue instance data variable, however once I click on an option because of the two-way binding it clears all the other options. Is there a way to just get the value but not clear all the other options after a selection.

example code:

```
<datalist id='list'>
    <option v-for='item in arrayOfObjects' :value='item'>
    </datalist>
</div>
</div>
```

Vue instance:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        optionVal: '',
        arrayOfObjects: [{key:'value'},{key:'value'},{key:'value'}],
    }
});
```

Comment: For a `v-for` in Vue needs to be an array not a single object.

Comment: Could you clarify more?

Comment: @Varcorb is mistaken. [See Here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object)

Comment: @Varcorb yes you're right, in my actual code it is infact an array of objects.

Comment: @AriVictor I don't mean to nitpick, but @Varcorb is not right. Whether you're using an array or not, Vue very specifically enables objects in a `v-for`. You can even separate the keys and values within a `v-for`. Answer coming soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem isn't two-way binding. It's that when you select an option, it filters out the rest of the options.

Solution:

On input, save the value then manually clear the input element.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    optionVal: "",
    arrayOfObjects: [{
      "name": "Coatimundi, white-nosed"
    }, {
      "name": "Dragon, netted rock"
    }, {
      "name": "Coot, red-knobbed"
    }, {
      "name": "Red-shouldered glossy starling"
    }, {
      "name": "Numbat"
    }, {
      "name": "Cat, toddy"
    }, {
      "name": "Square-lipped rhinoceros"
    }, {
      "name": "Griffon vulture"
    }, {
      "name": "Ibis, sacred"
    }, {
      "name": "Weeper capuchin"
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    saveSelectionAndReset(e) {
      let val = e.target.value;
      if (val) {
        this.optionVal = val;
      }
      e.target.value = "";
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body,input{font-family:futura,helvetica!important;text-transform:uppercase}body{height:100vw;background:linear-gradient(135deg,#13f1fc 0,#0470dc 100%)}#app{display:flex;justify-content:flex-start;align-items:center;flex-direction:column;padding:10px}input{border:none;box-shadow:0 20px 30px -15px rgba(0,0,0,.4);border-radius:3px;font-size:1.2rem;padding:8px;margin:5%}input:focus{outline:0}p{color:#fff;text-shadow:0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input placeholder="Select an Option" @input="saveSelectionAndReset" list="list"/>
  <datalist id="list">
    <option v-for="item in arrayOfObjects" :value="item.name">
  </datalist>
  <p>{{optionVal || 'None Selected'}}</p>
</div>
```